# Getting null when I send file reactjs to express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file, file-upload

I am trying to send files using react js to express the server. but when I send a file from the frontend I got a null value into the server.

Frontend: I have consol log into the frontend everything is ok into the frontend.

```
const ProductImport = function () {
    const [file, setFile] = useState<any>();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("");

    const saveFile = (e) => {
        setFile(e.target.files[0]);
        setFileName(e.target.files[0].name);
    };
    const uploadFile = async (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);
        formData.append("fileName", fileName);

        console.log(file);
        console.log(fileName);

        fetch('http://localhost:5000/upload-excel', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.insertedId) {
                    alert('excel Added')
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });

    };
    return (
        <form onSubmit={uploadFile}>
            <label htmlFor="formGroupExampleInput" className="form-label">Example label</label>
            <input type="file" onChange={saveFile} />
            <button type="submit">Upload</button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

Backend: The problem is with the backend, I got null

```
//MIddleware
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors());
app.use(fileupload());
app.use(express.static("files"));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }));

     app.post("/upload-excel", async (req, res) => {
            const file = req.files;
            console.log(file);
        });
```

Frontend console:

[image]

Backend console:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Express by default can't parse formData, you will have to use 3rd party package like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Few changes you will have to make, install multer `npm i multer` then

```
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'path/to/save/file' })

 app.post("/upload-excel", upload.single('excel-file'), async (req, res) => {
            const file = req.file;
            console.log(file);
        });
```

Comment: Still getting null

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Turns out just need to reference the right item

```
    app.post("/upload-excel", async (req, res) => {
        const file = req.files.file;
        console.log(file);

        //for people that want to write to disk 
        require("fs").writeFile(somepath, file.data, function(err) {
          console.log(err);
        });
});
```